# Python facebook-sdk post to page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to a Facebook Page I manage with the Python facebook-sdk but I can't figure out how to do it. I can post to my Facebook Wall like so:

```
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message='My message goes here')
```

I can get the pages I manage and the access tokens like so:

```
fbpages = graph.request('me/accounts')
```

But I can't find any resources to indicate how to actually then use the access token to post to the page. I imagine it would be something like this:

```
graph.put_object("me", "page id", "access token", message='My message goes here')
```

How would I actually go about doing this with the Python facebook-sdk?

I'm using 'pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk'.

Comment: You should probably tell what SDK you are using that have put_object. But for posting on your wall you do /me/feed. To post on a page wall you do /{page_id}/feed

Comment: Thanks you, that helped me figure it out. The page access token is used in place of the user access token when verifying with Facebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank's to WizKid for pointing me in the right direction. For anyone else with this problem it is solved like so:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
graph.put_object("page id", "feed", message='My message goes here')
```

Comment: Is this out of date..  I get a permissions error about.. QUOTE "If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission".  manage_pages/publish_pages exists in lates API app, manage_pages does not.  but pages_manage_cta does.  but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

With the new API(v2.8), you can use the following code:

```
import facebook
def main():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_user_access_token', version='2.8')
    #if version 2.8 show error use 2.6
    attachment =  {
        'name': 'Link name'
        'link': 'https://www.example.com/',
        'caption': 'Check out this example',
        'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
        'picture': 'https://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg'
    }

    graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', attachment=attachment, profile_id='your_page_id')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can change the attachment as your need. I think this will be helpful if someone needs to use the new API. You need to install facebook sdk first.

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```